# How should I use org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.gt?

Tags: mockito, assert, hamcrest

I'm trying to figure out how `org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers` works but I failed. Why is this test failing?

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.*;

public class DemoTest {

    @Test
    public void testGreaterThan() throws Exception {

        assertThat( 17
            , is( gt( 10 ) )
        );
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <0>
     got: <17>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use Hamcrest's `greaterThan` for this case. `gt` is for verifying arguments of method calls in mock objects:

```
public class DemoTest {

    private List<Integer> list = Mockito.mock(List.class);

    @Test
    public void testGreaterThan() throws Exception {
        assertThat(17, is(org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThan(10)));

        list.add(17);
        verify(list).add(org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.gt(10));
    }

}
```

Comment: You can reference org.hamcrest.Matchers with
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>